# Não consigo retornar todos os dados nos inputs com o PDO?

Tags: php, pdo

Criei uma pagina pra colocar o `cpf` e logo depois faz uma busca no banco, e traz os dados de acordo com o cpf digitado. mas tem alguns inputs que não estão voltando como `<radio>` (sexo M ou F), os `<select>` também não estão voltando, os `<textarea>` e os `<input type="checkbox">`.

aqui e o codigo php que faz a busca com o cpf digitado:

```
<?php  include("php/conexao.php"); $pdo=conectar(); 
       $cpf = $_POST['cpf']; 
       if(isset($cpf)){ 
         $consulta= $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM paciente where cpf = :cpf"); 
         $consulta->bindParam(":cpf",$cpf);
         $consulta->execute(); $resultado = $consulta->fetchAll(); print_r($resultado); 
       } 
       if(!$resultado){ 
        echo "<script>alert('Dados informados incorretamente!');history.back();</script>"; 
       } 
?>
```

aqui e onde os dados devem retornar em cada input conforme o banco de dados tb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>NutricLIFE</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="imagens/favicon.png" />
    </head>

    <body id="body1">

        <img id="emblema" src="imagens/emblema.png">

        <div id="body2">

            <div class="groupb1">
                <a href="index.html" class="botoes1">PDF</a>
            </div>

      <div class="groupb1">
        <a href="consultarPaciente.html" class="botoes1">voltar</a>
      </div>

    </div>

            <div class="box-paciente">

                <form action="#.php" method="get">

                    <h2>Dados do Paciente</h2>

                      <div>
                          <input class="campo-form-c" type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Nome" value=<?php print_r($resultado[0]['nome']); ?>>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                          <input class="campo-form-c" type="text" name="cpf" placeholder="CPF" value=<?php print_r($resultado[0]['cpf']); ?> >
                    </div>


                    <div>
                            <input class="campo-form-c" type="text" name="ultimopeso" placeholder="Ultimo peso" value=<?php print_r($resultado[0]['ultimopeso']); ?>></br>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                          <input class="campo-form-c" type="text" name="pesoatual" placeholder="Peso Atual" value=<?php print_r($resultado[0]['pesoatual']); ?>>
                      </div>

                    <div>
                        <input class="campo-form-c" type="text" name="altura" placeholder="Altura" value=<?php print_r($resultado[0]['altura']); ?>>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <input class="campo-form-c" type="number" name="idade" placeholder="Idade" value=<?php print_r($resultado[0]['idade']); ?>></br>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <input class="campo-form-c" type="text" name="datan" placeholder="Data de nascimento" value=<?php print_r($resultado[0]['datan']); ?>></br>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <div class="label-s">
                            <label>Sexo: </label>  
                                <label class="radio-inline">
                                    <input type="radio" name="sexo" value=<?php print_r($resultado[0]['sexo']); ?>>Masculino
                                </label>

                                <label class="radio-inline">
                                    <input type="radio" name="Sexo" value=<?php print_r($resultado[0]['sexo']); ?>>Feminino
                                </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                 <div>
            <input class="campo-form-c" type="text" name="medidab" placeholder="Medida do Braço" maxlength="5" value=<?php print_r($resultado[0]['medidab']); ?>>
          </div>

          <div>
            <input class="campo-form-c" type="text" name="medidat" placeholder="Medida Tricipital" maxlength="5" value=<?php print_r($resultado[0]['medidat']); ?>>
          </div>

            <div>
            <input class="campo-form-c" type="text" name="medidaabd" placeholder="Medida Abdominal" maxlength="5" value=<?php print_r($resultado[0]['medidaabd']); ?>></br>
            </div>

          <div>
            <input class="campo-form-c" type="text" name="imc" placeholder="IMC" maxlength="4" value=<?php print_r($resultado[0]['imc']); ?>>
          </div>

          <div>
            <input class="campo-form-c" type="text" name="gorduratricpital" placeholder="Gordura Tricipital" maxlength="5" value=<?php print_r($resultado[0]['gorduratricpital']); ?>>
          </div>

            <div>
            <input class="campo-form-c" type="text" name="circunferenciabraco" placeholder="Circunferência do Braço" maxlength="5" value=<?php print_r($resultado[0]['circunferenciabraco']); ?>></br>
            </div>


            <div>
            <input class="campo-form-c" type="text" name="circunferenciambraco" placeholder="Circunferência Muscular do Braço" maxlength="5" value=<?php print_r($resultado[0]['circunferenciambraco']); ?>></br>
            </div>

            <div>
            <input class="campo-form-c" type="text" name="gorduracorporal" placeholder="Gordura Corporal" maxlength="5" value=<?php print_r($resultado[0]['gorduracorporal']); ?>>
          </div>

            <div class="div-label">
              <label>Alguma alergia a medicamentos?</label> 
                <select class="select-form" name="alergiamedicamento" value=<?php print_r($resultado[0]['alergiamedicamento']); ?>>
                  <option>Sim</option>
                  <option>Não</option>
              </select>
              </div>

                    <div class="div-label">
                    <label>Utiliza algum medicamento?</label> 
                        <select class="select-form" name="algummedicamento" value=<?php print_r($resultado[0]['algummedicamento']); ?>>
                            <option>Sim</option>
                            <option>Não</option>
                    </select>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                    <label class="div-label">Quais?</label>
                        <textarea class="areat" name="quaismedicamentos" placeholder="Rascunho" value=<?php print_r($resultado[0]['quaismedicamentos']); ?>></textarea>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <input class="campo-form-c" type="text" name="tempomedicamento" placeholder="Tempo de medicamento" value=<?php print_r($resultado[0]['tempomedicamento']); ?>>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                    <label class="div-label">Bebe Água?</label> 
                        <select class="select-form" name="bebeagua" id="inputindex" value=<?php print_r($resultado[0]['bebeagua']); ?>>
                            <option>Sim</option>
                            <option>Não</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                       <div>
              <label class="div-label">Quantos copos?</label> 
                            <input class="select-form" type="number" name="quantoscopos" placeholder="Quantos Copos" value=<?php print_r($resultado[0]['quantoscopos']); ?>></br>
                   </div>

                    <div>
                    <label class="div-label">Frequência intestinal ?</label>
                        <select class="select-form" name="intestinal" value=<?php print_r($resultado[0]['intestinal']); ?>>
                            <option>Todos dos dias</option>
                            <option>Há cada dois dias</option>
                            <option>Há cada três dias</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                    <label class="div-label">Urina com Frequência ?</label> 
                        <select class="select-form" name="urina" value=<?php print_r($resultado[0]['urina']); ?>>
                            <option>Sim, todos os dias</option>
                            <option>Poucas vezes por dia</option>
                            <option>Quase não urino durante o dia</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                    <label class="div-label">Fuma ?</label> 
                        <select class="select-form" name="fuma" value=<?php print_r($resultado[0]['fuma']); ?>>
                            <option>Sim</option>
                            <option>Não</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div>   
                    <label class="div-label">Ingere Bebida alcoólica ?</label>
                        <select class="select-form"" name="alcool" value=<?php print_r($resultado[0]['alcool']); ?>>
                            <option>Sim</option>
                            <option>Não</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                    <label class="div-label">Pratica alguma atividade física ?</label>
                        <select class="select-form" name="atividadefisica" value=<?php print_r($resultado[0]['atividadefisica']); ?>>
                            <option>Sim</option>
                            <option>Não</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <input class="campo-form-c" type="text" name="pratica" placeholder="Qual atividade física ?" value=<?php print_r($resultado[0]['pratica']); ?>></br>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                    <label class="div-label">Quantas vezes por semana ?</label> <!-- quantas vezes por semana -->
                        <select class="select-form" name="vezes" value=<?php print_r($resultado[0]['vezes']); ?>>
                            <option>0</option>
                            <option>1</option>
                            <option>2</option>
                            <option>3</option>
                            <option>4</option>
                            <option>5</option>
                            <option>6</option>
                            <option>7</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                    <label class="div-label">Intenção da Consulta ?</label> <!-- intenção da consulta -->
                        <textarea class="areat" name="consulta" placeholder="Rascunho" value=<?php print_r($resultado[0]['consulta']); ?>></textarea>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                    <label class="div-label">Problemas de Saúde ?</label> <!-- problema de saúde -->
                        <select class="select-form" name="saude" value=<?php print_r($resultado[0]['saude']); ?>>
                            <option>Sim</option>
                            <option>Não</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                    <label class="div-label">Histórico familiar ?</label> <!-- histórico familiar -->
                        <textarea class="areat" name="familiar" placeholder="Rascunho" value=<?php print_r($resultado[0]['familiar']); ?>></textarea>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                    <label class="div-label">Possui alergia a algum alimento ?</label> 
                         <textarea class="areat" name="comment" name="alergia" placeholder="Rascunho" value=<?php print_r($resultado[0]['alergia']); ?>></textarea>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                    <label class="div-label">Anamnese Alimentar: O que o paciente costuma comer de segunda a sexta ?</label> <!-- o que costuma comer de segunda a sexta-->
                        <textarea class="areat" name="anamnese" placeholder="Rascunho" value=<?php print_r($resultado[0]['anamnese']); ?>></textarea>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                    <label class="div-label">E sábado e domingo ?</label> <!-- o que costuma comer sabado e domingo-->
                        <textarea class="areat" name="sabadoedomingo" placeholder="Rascunho" value=<?php print_r($resultado[0]['sabadoedomingo']); ?>></textarea>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <label class="div-label">Tem exames recentes de Sangue? Urina ? Fezes? (Menos de 3 meses)</label>
                        </div>

                    <div class="checkb">
                            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="examesf" value=<?php print_r($resultado[0]['examesf']); ?> >Sangue |
                            </label>
                            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="examesf" value=<?php print_r($resultado[0]['examesf']); ?>>Urina |
                            </label>
                            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="examesf" value=<?php print_r($resultado[0]['examesf']); ?>>Fezes |
                            </label>
                            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="examesf" value=<?php print_r($resultado[0]['examesf']); ?>>Sem examesf
                            </label>
                        </div>

                            <textarea class="areat" name="examesfr" placeholder="Rascunho" value=<?php print_r($resultado[0]['examesfr']); ?>></textarea>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <label class="div-label">Solicitar exames :</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkb">
                            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="examess" value=<?php print_r($resultado[0]['examess']); ?>>Sangue |
                            </label>
                            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="examess" value=<?php print_r($resultado[0]['examess']); ?>>Urina |
                            </label>
                            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="examess" value=<?php print_r($resultado[0]['examess']); ?>>Fezes 
                            </label>
                        </div>

                            <textarea class="areat" name="examessr" placeholder="Rascunho" value=<?php print_r($resultado[0]['examessr']); ?>></textarea>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

usando o print_r no codigo php ele retorna o array:

> `Array ( [0] => Array ( [id_paciente] => 1004 [0] => 1004 [nome] => fulano [1] => fulano [cpf] => 111.111.111-11 [2] => 111.111.111-11 [ultimopeso] => 90 [3] => 90 [pesoatual] => 75 [4] => 75 [altura] => 1.93 [5] => 1.93 [idade] => 20 [6] => 20 [datan] => 11-11-2000 [7] => 11-11-2000 [sexo] => M [8] => M [medidab] => 12.34 [9] => 12.34 [medidat] => 12.54 [10] => 12.54 [medidaabd] => 32.54 [11] => 32.54 [imc] => 12.3 [12] => 12.3 [gorduratricpital] => 50.32 [13] => 50.32 [circunferenciabraco] => 12 [14] => 12 [circunferenciambraco] => 12 [15] => 12 [gorduracorporal] => 12 [16] => 12 [alergiamedicamento] => Sim [17] => Sim [algummedicamento] => Sim [18] => Sim [quaismedicamentos] => exemplo. [19] => exemplo. [tempomedicamento] => exemplo. [20] => exemplo. [bebeagua] => Sim [21] => Sim [quantoscopos] => 10 [22] => 10 [intestinal] => Todos dos dias [23] => Todos dos dias [urina] => Quase n�o urino durante o dia [24] => Quase n�o urino durante o dia [fuma] => Sim [25] => Sim [alcool] => Sim [26] => Sim [atividadefisica] => Sim [27] => Sim [pratica] => exemplo. [28] => exemplo. [vezes] => 7 [29] => 7 [consulta] => exemplo. [30] => exemplo. [saude] => Sim [31] => Sim [familiar] => exemplo. [32] => exemplo. [alergia] => exemplo. [33] => exemplo. [anamnese] => exemplo. [34] => exemplo. [sabadoedomingo] => exemplo. [35] => exemplo. [examesf] => Fezes [36] => Fezes [examesfr] => exemplo. [37] => exemplo. [examess] => Sangue [38] => Sangue [examessr] => exemplo. [39] => exemplo. ) )`

mas os `input` que comentei no começo ainda não chegam. `<radio>` (sexo M ou F), os `<select>` também não estão voltando, os `<textarea>` e os `<input type="checkbox">`.

Answer (score 1):

Os inputs do tipo `checkbox`, `radio` e `select` tem o valor padrão setado de forma diferente de `inputs` do tipo `text`.

Para `checkbox` e `radio` funciona da mesma forma. Você deve adicionar o atributo `checked`. Que pode ser ele sozinho ou `checked="checked"` (do xHTML):

```
<?php 

$isMale = $resultado[0]['sexo'] == "M" ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
$isFemale = $resultado[0]['sexo'] == "F" ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; 

?>

<input type="radio" name="sexo" value="M" <?= $isMale; ?> />Masculino
<input type="radio" name="Sexo" value="F" <?= $isFemale; ?> />Feminino
```

Essa disposição funciona tanto para `radio` quanto `checkbox`.

Quanto ao `select`, você deve definir qual `option` do `select` é que está selecionado. É similar ao `checkbox`, só que, ao invés de `checked` será `selected`.

Como você utiliza valores fixos no HTML, pode ser feito de forma parecida com o `checkbox`.

```
<?php 

$isTrue = $resultado[0]['saude'] == "S" ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
$isFalse = $resultado[0]['saude'] == "N" ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; 

?>

<select class="select-form" name="saude">
    <option value="S" <?= $isTrue; ?> />Sim</option>
    <option value="N" <?= $isFalse; ?> />Não</option>
 </select>
```

Outro ponto, `select` não possui o atributo `value`, quem possui esse atributo é o `option` que está dentro do `select`.

Por último, mas não menos importante, o `textarea` também não possui o atributo `value`. Diferente dos `inputs`, que é uma tag sem fechamento, o `textarea` precisa de tag de abertura e fechamento. O conteúdo/valor do `textarea` deve ser inserido entre as tags:

```
<textarea class="areat" name="quaismedicamentos" placeholder="Rascunho"><?=  $resultado[0]['quaismedicamentos']; ?></textarea>
```

**Outras considerações**

Em todo o seu código, você está utilizando `print_r`, `print_r` não é para *output* do valor da variável, e sim para exibir as informações, com uma fácil leitura (*human-readable*), de uma variável. No seu caso, você deve usar apenas `print` ou `echo`.

O seu HTML também está com alguns problemas, por isso não há o retorno certo para salvar no banco de dados.

O `radio` está com nomes diferentes. O primeiro está `Sexo` e o segundo `sexo`. Ele é case sensitive, deve manter sempre o mesmo case.

Já no caso do `checkbox`, ele deve ser tratado como `array`. Nesse caso, todos os seus `inputs` do tipo `checkbox` devem ter o `name` com a simbologia do `array` (`name="examesf[]"`).

Então, seus checkbox seriam:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="examesf[]"/>
```

Lá no PHP, você pode *iterar* sobre os valores selecionados:

```
foreach($_POST['examesf'] as $value)
{
    echo $value;
}
```

Somente para explicação. Se o `checkbox` possuir um valor setado (`value`), somente valores selecionados serão enviados ao PHP. Se o `checkbox` for de `name` único e não possuir valor, o PHP receberá o valor (`On`/`Off`).

Comment: ajudou bastante, porem estou com dificuldade no 'selected' naõ estou consigo passar os valores do 'option', queria saber se essa e a unica maneira, ou se que estou fazendo errado então. Outra coisa no 'checkbox' estou com dificuldade mas isso deve ser pq não estou salvado certo no banco, pq no check tem 5 ou 3 opções e no banco só salva 1 mesmo marcando todas as opções juntas, apenas salva 1 opção. no no html com os checkbox te esta assim so 'name=exames' 'value=sangue', 'value=urina', 'value=sem exame',

Comment: @BrunoD.assis Qual está sendo o problema com o `select`? Atualize sua questão com a dificuldade. Quanto a questão do `checkbox` é porque sua modelagem está errada. Precisa ter uma segunda tabela para salvar os dados dos `checkbox` e relacionar com o registro que você salva. De uma olhada [nesse artigo](http://rberaldo.com.br/usando-campos-multivalorados/). De qualquer forma, essa última questão seria interessante ser uma outra pergunta (pois, o foco dessa aqui é outro).